# seperate string characters by comma in c# 3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a string like `SetCode="ABCD"`
I want to convert it into `SetCode="A,B,C,D"`
I have tried `SetCode=string.Join(",", obj.SetCode.ToCharArray())`
but the error is shown:The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments
I am using c# 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this.

```
var setCode = "ABCD";
setCode = string.Join(",", setCode.Select(x => x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray());
```